# What is std:: used in conjunction with aside from cout and endl?

Tags: c++, std

My program originally used `using namespace std;` but I have heard from numerous people that this is bad programming practice so I want to break the habit. I changed all of the `cout`s and `endl`s in my program to `std::cout` and `std::endl;`.

Aside from `cout` and `endl`, what uses the namespace `std`? For example: I have vectors and strings in my program; do they use `std::`?

A list would be nice if it's not too long or too much of a hassle.

Comment: Just try to compile the code, and if some `std::` is missing the compiler will say that it does not recognize the name.

Comment: You can add `using std::...` for your most used constructions and continue using them without prefix `std` like `using std::cout; cout << "Without prefix";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example: I have vectors and strings in my program; do they use `std::`?

Yes. Vectors and strings are part of the standard library. The members of the `std` namespace are in the `standard library`.

> A list would be nice if it's not too long or too much of a hassle.

I can't give you a long, concise list. But I can show you how to find the members of the standard library. For example, take your other question. Are strings and vectors part of the standard library?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/

If we go here, click on 'Strings library' we can infact see the different types of strings we can employ in our C++ program. This process is the same for vectors, under the 'Containers library' section we can see `vector`, `list`, `map` etc.

If you have an IDE, you can also view the members of the standard library by prefacing your statement with `std::` -

[image]

Although you do have to have a matching header file included to see members of the standard library, the headers are named as you'd expect,

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

Comment: std:: is a namespace, not a library. Please don't confuse the two terms.

Comment: @H.Guijt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library _"Features of the C++ Standard Library are declared within the std namespace."_. I fail to see your point.

Comment: `std` is a namespace. It's not the name of a library, and the article you link to clearly explains this.

Comment: @H.Guijt `std` = **st**andar**d**  `std` is the namespace of the standard library, I've made it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Dumping the entire std namespace into your program is perhaps not the wisest choice, but I wouldn't be troubled by using specific elements from std. So instead of writing `using namespace std` you can use `using std::cout`, `using std::endl`, etc. Having to qualify lots and lots of code does not, in my opinion, help readability.

As for what's in std, it's a very long list, including all of STL. Just try to compile and see where the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

In short:
For **everything** in the C++ standard library.

That includes datastructures, algorithms, input output functions, type_traits, string manipulation, almost everything you can find in the C standard library... . You can find a list e.g. at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all types and functions provided by the C++ standard library are in namespace `std`.   Roughly speaking, this includes everything in standard headers without a `.h` in their filename - like `<vector>`, `<iostream>` (which brings in `std::cout`), `<string>` (`std::string`), `<algorithm>` (standard algorithms), and EVERY other standard C++ header file.    It does not include the C standard library (`<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, etc) although these do have equivalents in the C++ standard library (`<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>`, etc) which do place their declarations into namespace `std`.

There is no point in writing a list.   If you are using any part of the C++ standard library, you will be working with namespace `std`.  So any reference of the C++ standard library is the defacto list.

There are a couple of exceptions (e.g. names in the standard headers that are specified to be macros) but those are rare.